# Bootstrap col overlap in Firefox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am having trouble trying to figure out why my bootstraps website shows up fine in chrome however, when viewed in firefox the grid system is incorrect. 
In chrome everything appears normal however with firefox the columns greatly overlap. My site is daniellerandolph.com.

I can not seem to figure out how to fix this problem so the site is viewed consistently.